# I have a video background on my bootstrap page - how can I make it "fixed"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/22/ and as you can see here on first "section" I have the video background. Now, when user scrolls the webpage down, so far the whole video goes up. I would like to achieve the effect that the webpage overlaps it, so the video and its section is fixed to the page. I have the following CSS code:

```
.video-container2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container2 video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

and I tried to add:

```
position: fixed
```

instead of absolute, but it didn't do the trick...
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: fixed` will do the trick, but you need to set the `top/left/bottom/right` with `0` instead of `0%`:

```
.video-container2 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

With `bottom` and `right` set, you don't need `height` and `width` anymore.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/23/

---

In the comments, we talked about centering the video, even with oversize, and having it fill the viewport no matter the size of the screen. The only way to properly achieve that was with JavaScript. Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setVideoSize();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    setVideoSize();
});

function setVideoSize() {
    // ratio of video in pixels, width/height
    var videoRatio = 320 / 176;

    // ratio of window in pixels, width/height
    var screenRatio = $(window).width() / $(window).height();

    if (videoRatio < screenRatio) {
        $('.video-container2 video').width($(window).width());
        $('.video-container2 video').height('auto');
    } else {
        $('.video-container2 video').height($(window).height());
        $('.video-container2 video').width('auto');
    }
}
```

And to center it, we can use this sort of hacky CSS:

```
.video-container2 video {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  right: -9999px;
  bottom: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/28/

Comment: thanks! is there a way of stretching the video, so that when e.g. I make the browser window really small it will not adjust the height to the width, and instead it will zoom into the video a little (or stretch it so that the whole text on section one has it as a background)?

Comment: http://themes.semicolonweb.com/html/canvas/one-page/op-video-event.php this is a nice example - no matter how I resize the page, the video is always adjusting its size... How can I achieve that kind of effect?

Comment: Yep! Set a `min-width` and a `min-height` on `.video-container2 video`. Then it won't ever go below that size.

Comment: If you want to always have it zoom to the center instead of the top left, it takes a bit more of a hack. Here's a jsfiddle with the mins and the centering: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/26/

Comment: The example you linked sets the video size using JavaScript based on the size of the user's browser. That is why it works so nicely. You could do that, but that's a whole new question if you need help with it, haha.

Comment: thanks Michal, that's really helpful. Can you give me some brief explanation how exactly their js works for that? or maybe is there any tutorial/example that I could use?

Comment: I made a quick fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/28/ with the jQuery that does it

Comment: you see, this is why I like Stack Overflow community so much. It is really helpful, even in the smallest corner cases ;) thank you very much Michal! :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your top/left values to `0` instead of `0%`.

```
.video-container2{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/25/